# Does android device keeps info about inapp purchase?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Does android device keeps info about inapp purchase? Or it need connection to google play to verify info about purchases?

Comment: All your answers are there: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Not Device, but Account

All your purchases and inApp or otherwise, are stored against your google account.

> **So, wherever your account goes, your purchased items go.**

Comment: ie if no internet connection on user device, application cannot check users purchases?

Comment: Yes and No. Let me clarify, applications ask play store if this item is bought, and play store replies with an answer. These answers are cached locally, so when internet is not there, it functions if a cached reply is available.

Comment: I'm testing example from google and found that after deleting/installing application GPlay send message about purchase, even if no internet connection.

Comment: One more question - how much time Google Play stores cache about purchase. May be unlimited time or it have some limits?

Comment: @AntonNikitin What do you mean send message, do you mean email? If you're making a purchase I reckon you have internet connection, probably that's how the "message" was sent.

I'm not really sure about the caching policy, but an educated guess would be that it stays there as long as the app is installed. Or probably as long as the purchased user's account is connected.